# C# : Change String Encoding?

Tags: c#, json, string, encoding

I'm struggling with the encoding of one of my string.

On a Mail Sending WS, I'm receiving a bad string containing  "�" instead of "é" (that's what I'm seeing in the Debug Mode of Visual Studio at least).
The character comes from some JSON that is deserialized when entering the WS into my DTO.

Changing the Content-Type of the JSON is not solving the thing.
So I thought I'll change the encoding of my string by myself, because the JSON encoding thing seems like a VS deserialization issue (I started a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874837/charset-messing-up-in-vs-2008-json-deserialization) if one of you guys want to take a look at it).

I tried :

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding defaultEncoding = Encoding.Default;
byte[] bytes = defaultEncoding.GetBytes(messedUpString);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(defaultEncoding, iso, bytes);
cleanString = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

Or :

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(messedUpString);
cleanString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

And it's not really effective... I get rid of the "�" char, which is the nice part, but I'm receiving in the cleanString "?" instead of the expected "é", and this in not really nice, or at least, the expected behavior.

Comment: If your data is already a `string` it's too late to fix it. You need to use the correct encoding when you first convert your data from bytes into a string.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I can't change this. This is a MVC2 method controller, and the Deserialisation feature is part of the Framework.This means I can't do anything to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, you *have* to change it as there is no other way to fix it. You can configure the input encoding in ASP.NET, and it should be able to detect it from the headers as well. As a last resort you can always read the request body as binary and decode it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, every thing was fine in my application.

I used SOAPUI to test, and this was my error. 
I downloaded some rest plugin for my browser, try from there, and everything worked.

Thanks for the help though @MattiVirkkunen